# Can the 0 Gravity of a hollow shell be rephrased to "If an object has a gravitational counterpoint net forces become 0"?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

So the basic argument as I understand it for gravity inside a hollow shell is all gravitational forces are equal to 0, because they cancel out from the mass on the other side of the shell irrespective of location. Could that be thought of more generally as if you have a gravitational counterpoint then the force of gravity becomes 0.

Example: In deep space away from all other gravity influences & frictionless. You have 2 rocks of equal mass on either side of a 3rd rock. Do their individual gravities cancel out relative to the 3rd object in between 1 & 2.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have two bodies of mass $M$ separated by a distance $d$. If you place a test body *exactly in the center* of the line separating the two objects, then the force on that object will be zero. *However*, the force will *not* be zero if you place the test body anywhere else. Furthermore, the test body placed at the center is not in a *stable* equilibrium, because any small nudge that pushes it toward one of the two other masses, will cause the gravitational force to continue to pull it toward that mass.

The situation inside a hollow sphere is quite different. There, the force is zero *everywhere* inside the shell. A small perturbation or nudge to the position of the object, will not lead to an unstable situation in which the force gets larger in the direction of the small perturbation.

There is more "magic" going on with a hollow shell, than simply saying that every point on the shell has a corresponding point on the opposite side of the shell. This reflection symmetry only guarantees that the force is zero at the center of the shell, which as we have seen is a *much* weaker condition. The cancellation that leads to zero force inside the shell crucially relies on the fact that gravity is an inverse *square* law (the force is proportional to $r^{-2}$, the $-2$ is very important), which ultimately is balanced by the fact that the surface area of a sphere grows as $r^2$. If you work thorugh the details, you will find you need a more sophisticated argument, than the one you present in your question, in order to conclude that the force is zero everywhere inside the shell.

Comment: Ok, rock 1 & 2 are MgB², rock 3 is NbFeB. Ambient temperature is 20K average temperature of space is 2.7k. MgB² is superconducting. So flux pinning is stopping rock 1 & rock 2 from being displaced by a kinetic collision. How many pairs of these rocks before gravity can be considered cancelled out?
  https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Physics_(Boundless)/5%3A_Uniform_Circular_Motion_and_Gravitation/5.5%3A_Newtons_Law_of_Universal_Gravitation#:~:text=Isaac%20Newton%20proved%20the%20Shell,inside%20of%20it%20is%20zero.